# Get Time Difference between two datetime in Oracle

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, oracle10g, oracle-apex

Situation 1 :

```
p_start_date = 13.Apr.2012 13:00
p_end_date = 13.Apr.2012 15:00

working_hours = 0

// in this Situation working_hours should be 2
```

Situation 2 :

```
p_start_date = 13.Apr.2012 13:00
p_end_date = 14.Apr.2012 15:00

working_hours = 24

// in this Situation working_hours should be 26
```

When i run this on `SQLDevelopper` with `Situation 1` and `Situation 2`, values for `working_hours` is return correctly. but i call this Procedure in `Before Insert Update Trigger` for use in my apex application. when i submit tabular form with `Situation 1`, value for `working_hours` is `0` and when i submit tabular form with `Situation 2`, value for `working_hours` is `24`.

According to `Situation 1` and `Situation 2`, difference between two dates assign to working_hours. but my need is get difference between two times.

How could i do that ?

My Procedure to calculate `working_hours`  is,

```
PROCEDURE get_labour_cost_data(
 p_employee_id IN NUMBER,
 p_start_date IN VARCHAR2,
 p_end_date IN VARCHAR2,
 hours_normal_rate OUT NUMBER,
 working_hours OUT NUMBER,
 total_cost OUT NUMBER)

 AS

 v_employee_rate NUMBER;

 BEGIN

  if p_employee_id is null then

    hours_normal_rate := 0; 
    working_hours := 0;
    total_cost := 0;

  elsif p_employee_id is not null then

    -- Get hourse_noraml from employee
    select HOURLY_SALARY into hours_normal_rate from Employee
    where EMPLOYEE_ID = p_employee_id;

    -- Get working hours   
    working_hours := 24 * (to_date(p_end_date, 'dd.mm.rr hh24:mi') - to_date(p_start_date, 'dd.mm.rr hh24:mi'));

    -- Get Total cost   
    total_cost := nvl(hours_normal_rate,0) * nvl(working_hours,0);

    end if;    
  END;
```

Trigger is,

```
create or replace
TRIGGER LABOUR_COST_BIU_TRI 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON LABOUR_COST 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

v_hours_normal NUMBER;
v_working_hours NUMBER;
v_total_cost NUMBER;
BEGIN

    util.get_labour_cost_data(
    p_employee_id => :NEW.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    p_start_date => :NEW.START_DATE_TIME,
    p_end_date => :NEW.END_DATE_TIME,
    hours_normal_rate => v_hours_normal,
    working_hours => v_working_hours,
    total_cost => v_total_cost
  );

      select v_hours_normal, v_working_hours, v_total_cost into :NEW.HOURS_NOMAL, :NEW.HOURS_OT, :NEW.TOTAL_COST
  from dual;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

When I create and run your procedure alone it works:

```
declare
 hours_normal_rate NUMBER;
 working_hours NUMBER;
 total_cost NUMBER;
begin
get_labour_cost_data(
 1,
 '13.Apr.2012 13:00',
 '13.Apr.2012 15:00',
 hours_normal_rate,
 working_hours,
 total_cost);
 dbms_output.put_Line(working_hours);
END;
```

Output:

```
2
```

And:

```
declare
 hours_normal_rate NUMBER;
 working_hours NUMBER;
 total_cost NUMBER;
begin
get_labour_cost_data(
 1,
 '13.Apr.2012 13:00',
 '14.Apr.2012 15:00',
 hours_normal_rate,
 working_hours,
 total_cost);
 dbms_output.put_Line(working_hours);
END;
```

Output:

```
25.99999999999999999999999999999999999992
```

(Close!)

I can't see any problem with the way you use it in the trigger, though that could be simplified to:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER LABOUR_COST_BIU_TRI 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON LABOUR_COST 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    util.get_labour_cost_data(
    p_employee_id => :NEW.EMPLOYEE_ID,
    p_start_date => :NEW.START_DATE_TIME,
    p_end_date => :NEW.END_DATE_TIME,
    hours_normal_rate => :NEW.HOURS_NOMAL,
    working_hours => :NEW.HOURS_OT,
    total_cost => :NEW.TOTAL_COST
  );

END;
```